# Append an element to Array of Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, append

Suppose I have an array of arrays.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

I want to add 10 as the first element of each of those arrays without running for loop. Result should look like

```
array([[10, 1, 2],
       [10, 3, 4],
       [10, 5, 6]])
```

Plain append does not work.

```
np.append(10, x)
array([10,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6])
```

My original problem has 100K arrays. So I need to find an efficient way to do this.

Comment: That is not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for np.insert.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

`np.insert(x, 0, [10,10,10], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

np.insert is your choice

```
>>> import numpy as np
x = np.array([ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

>>> x
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

>>> np.insert(x, 0, 10, axis=1)

array([[10,  1,  2],
       [10,  3,  4],
       [10,  5,  6]])
```

you also can insert different values

```
>>> np.insert(x, 0, [10,11,12] , axis=1)

array([[10,  1,  2],
       [11,  3,  4],
       [12,  5,  6]])
```